# How to rotate SwiftUI Path around its center?

Tags: ios, swiftui, path, rotation, transform

I have the following simple SwiftUI `Path` of an arrow which I wish to rotate around it's center:

```
@State var heading: Double = 0.0
@State var xOffset = 0.0
@State var yOffset = 0.0
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        NavigationStack {
            Path { path in
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: xOffset, y: yOffset))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xOffset + 0, y: yOffset + 20))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xOffset + 50, y: yOffset + 0))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xOffset + 0, y: yOffset - 20))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xOffset + 0, y: yOffset + 0))
            }
            .stroke(lineWidth: 3)
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: heading), anchor: .center)
            .transformEffect(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 80, y: 80))

            Slider(value: $heading, in: 0...360, step: 30)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: At 0º]

It does however not rotate around its center:

[image: At 30º]

How can I rotate a `Path` around its center (or around any other relative point on its bounds)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Path` view greedily takes up all of the space available to it, so the view is much larger than you think, and its center is far away.  So when you rotate the path, it moves off the screen.  You can see this by adding `.background(Color.yellow)` to the `Path` view.

It's easier to manage the rotation of the arrow if you make it an `.overlay` of another `View` (`Color.clear`) and then rotate that `View`.  You can make the view visible by using `Color.yellow` while tuning, and then position the arrow relative to its parent view.  The nice thing about this is that when you rotate the parent view, the arrow will stick to it and rotate predictably.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var heading: Double = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationStack {
                Color.clear
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                    .overlay (
                        Path { path in
                            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
                            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 20))
                            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 0))
                            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -20))
                            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
                        }
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 3)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .offset(x: 5, y: 30)
                    )
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: heading), anchor: .center)
                
                Slider(value: $heading, in: 0...360, step: 30)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: arrow rotating in simulator]

---

### How do I make my code work?

You need to give your `Path` view a reasonable sized `frame`.  Here I added `.frame(width: 60, height: 60)` which is big enough to hold your arrow path.

Since you have defined `xOffset` and `yOffset`, use them to move the path drawing within its view.  Temporarily add a background to your path view with `.background(Color.yellow)` and then adjust `xOffset` and `yOffset` until your arrow is drawing inside of that view.  You can then remove this `.background`.

This has the same effect as the overlay method presented above:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var heading: Double = 0.0
    @State var xOffset = 5.0   // here
    @State var yOffset = 30.0  // here

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationStack {
                Path { path in
                    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: xOffset, y: yOffset))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xOffset + 0, y: yOffset + 20))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xOffset + 50, y: yOffset + 0))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xOffset + 0, y: yOffset - 20))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xOffset + 0, y: yOffset + 0))
                }
                .stroke(lineWidth: 3)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                // .background(Color.yellow)
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)  // here
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: heading), anchor: .center)
                //.transformEffect(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 80, y: 80))

                Slider(value: $heading, in: 0...360, step: 30)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  For my understanding, would you be willing to explain what happened in my code, how my code could be made to work, and why your code works?

Comment: What happens when there's no 'reasonable' frame?  Why does my arrow rotate around a point far outside the visible screen?

Comment: A reasonable frame is just one that holds your path drawing.  Certainly you can find that by figuring out your leftmost, topmost, rightmost, and bottommost points.  Your arrow is rotating around the center of the view.  The view by default is large.  As initially drawn, your arrow was part of the way outside of the view bounds which added to the problem.